# Knob removal on dresser

Tags: furniture

I have a dresser that I am trying to swap the knobs on. It's a 5 piece drawer, and I can get the screw out of the knob, but the knob doesn't come off. I can (hopefully) gorilla it off, but I want to be sure it's not common to attach the knobs in some way other than a screw.[image]

Comment: Might just be sticky.  Maybe try low heat(hair dryer).  Did the screw seem loose/jumpy when taking it out?  Possible the screw was stripped and someone used glue to hold the knob on, but betting on sticky.

Comment: Maybe try giving it a love tap with a rubber mallet (or 2x4)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A screw through the drawer and into the knob is the only way I've ever seen this done. The knob was probably installed before the finish was completely dried and firmly stuck to the wood. Work it back and forth and it should break free. Maybe tap it gently with a  mallet.

Based on some good comments, cutting around the knob with a small blade might prevent pulling off some of the finish.

Comment: I'd run a sharp knife or chisel around the joint between the handle and the drawer face to break any surface connection, and then tap it from the side with a softer hammer.  Cutting will reduce the chance of splintering (if glued) or tearing a nurny in the finish.

Comment: @Criggie I agree.  Just about any X-ACTO knife is perfect for this task.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do. I removed the screw and with a small tap, they came right off. It pulled a little of the finish off, but of course that is covered by the new knob. Thank you!

Comment: 'Pulled a little finish off.' This answer would be a lot better with the instruction to cut around the knob. That way, the next person doesn't also pull a little (or a lot of) finish off.

Answer (score 3):

Your drawer has two pieces at the front: a structural piece, similar to the sides, and a decorative front piece with the finish. The knob is likely held on with a screw.  If you can't see a screw behind the knob then it was probably attached to the finished front before the finished front itself was attached, so the screw head for the knob is between the two pieces.

Are there a couple of screws inside the drawer holding the finished front on? If so, removing these will let you unscrew the knob. If the finished front is glued on,  it will be more difficult.

Comment: Note, the OP says he already removed the (machine) screw.